# Is it possible to implement gradient checking in a vectorized way when implementing neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

For example, I add delta to all dimensions of w from y=w.dot(x)+b and calculate dw in one time?

Comment: By gradient checking, do you mean verifying gradient descent is working? Have you checked out this link? http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Gradient_checking_and_advanced_optimization

Comment: I checked that. That is  checking the gradient once a parameter. I want to check many once a time.